# explode and in_Array search not working

Tags: php

OK here is the code codepad here http://codepad.org/ZQz0Kn3R

```
function processContent($content, $min_count = 2, $exclude_list = array()) {
    $wordsTmp = explode(' ', str_replace(array('(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', "'", '"', ':', ',', '.', '?'), ' ', $content));
    $words = array();
$wordsTmp2 = array();
$omit = array('and', 'or', 'but', 'yet', 'for', 'not', 'so', '&', '&amp;', '+', '=', '-', '*', '/', '^', '_', '\\', '|');
if(count($exclude_list)>0){
    $omit = array_merge($omit, $exclude_list);
}
foreach ($wordsTmp as $wordTmp) {
   if (!empty($wordTmp) && !in_array($wordTmp, $omit) && strlen($wordTmp) >= $min_count) {
             $words[] = $wordTmp;
    }
}
return $words;
}
```

OK this is my function which should return array of words by filtering from `$omit` variable. But when i use it the words in first `$omit` array are only filtered, The second merged from the `$exclude_list` is not filtered.

I use my function this way :

```
$filter_array = explode("\n", words list separated by \n new line here);
print_r(processContent('String gere for filtering', $min_word_length, $filter_array));
```

The variable `$filter_array` is passed in to the exclude_list also is merged to omit variable but does not get filtered in return value. only first `$omit` value is filtered. Is there something wrong in code??

Comment: http://codepad.org/lkg9JQqJ see this codepad. same error

Comment: Your codepad example should surely be array('of','for') rather than array('of,for')

Comment: it's the first one. http://codepad.org/e4lPjHFC

Comment: it works in codepad but not on my server

Comment: What do you get on your server?

Comment: ok here is the problem i found it's actually to do with explode i think. 
i am passing $filter_array by doin explode on the list of words. 
$filter_words = explode("\n", $_POST['filter_words']);
when i simply pass array it works but does not works when i pass it through the explode function.

Comment: explode returns an array, and so it cant be used to search in another array.

Comment: http://codepad.org/ZQz0Kn3R here is the codepad for it

Comment: how to fix this issue dskanth?

Comment: I know it returns an array but why can't it be used in in_array function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `$filter_array` has spaces in it.  Either:

```
$filter_array = array_map(function($el) { return trim($el); }, $filter_array);
```

Or

```
foreach ($filter_array as &$element) {
    $element = trim($element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codepad.viper-7.com/BrZ9Rm

you will need to pass it through trim:

```
$filter_array = array_map(function($el) { return trim($el); }, $filter_array);
```